# Is there any good website to view running trails in the Bellevue, WA area?

Tags: running

I'm in Bellevue, WA this week and am trying to find some good places to run. I'm sure I can just find a park and do many loops, but I'm looking for some mapped runs of 7-10 miles. I'm sure if a website is mentioned, it would be larger than just this area, but I'm particularly focused on Bellevue.

Comment: I would rephrase the question to have it less localized, which is one of the flagging/closing reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lists of Bellevue trails here:

- http://www.bellevuewa.gov/nature_trails.htm
- http://www.bellevuewa.gov/pedbike/TrailPlanMap.aspx

I like the Coal Creek Natural Area park, and you can run a good portion of it (though it is a hike for a good part of it more than runnable - too many slippery spots).

Also, I really enjoy the stretch of trail through the wetlands between Factoria and Enatai.  It's more of a biking/walking trail, and it seems like running might get you run down because you'd be in the way of bikers, and less able to hear their bells.  But it is a really nice walk during the summer.  It hooks up to other bits of road that run off into parks with trails, too.  I think the route is close to one side of the Mercer Slough park.

Answer (score 9):

I travel a fair bit and always want to run in the places I visit, so I have the same problem. I usually try the following:

- Google for runs using the search terms "running in <your location>" - that will very, very often come up with a site or two for official running clubs in your area. And they usually have a number of suggestions.
- For the US, I have successfully used [Running in the USA](http://www.runningintheusa.com/).
- On a more global scale, I use [MapMyRUN](http://www.mapmyrun.com/routes/?) and [Endomondo (you must log-in first)](http://www.endomondo.com/routes/).

For Bellevue, WA Endomondo returned 200+ routes in and about the city center...

Comment: MapMyRun has a great selection of runs from its users all over the world.

Answer (score -1):

check out http://www.runmap.net/ and http://www.wandermap.net/